# Is this possible? Track function calls of c++ application

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, trace

Ok, this is a bit far fetched but here is the idea and question: is it possible to get any kind of 'reference' (memory pointer, function identifier or whatever data) from a running Windows application on an event trigger basis?

Why? just like screen **scraper** are trying to make legacy application translatable to some programatic api call, I'm looking for ways to identify button clicks in a legacy window application: I don't need to know what the button is or does at first, but I need to be able to record a unique ID for a button click.
Screen **scrapers** record clicks to 'replay' later but this is not the goal: the goal is to record clicks as they happen and build the user 'journey' through the app like Web site record browsing journey.

Any idea of what technology would allow this?

I'm thinking debugger like tracing of the pointer location associated with a click event, but not sure how that's applicable to a compiled packaged app.

Maybe it's just not possible; I can see how that may be a security issue, but if it is, I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: This is confusing.. you're talking about function calls, but then later all you care about is what happens in the UI.

Comment: From a programmatic point of view, the mechanism used in windows is called ***CBT***, and it is a major pain to implement.  You might have better luck if you just look for ready-made software for ***macro recording and playback***.  Also, this is the type of stuff that malicious software does, so be prepared for an uphill battle against all sorts of virus scanners.

Comment: I care about what happens in the UI but a UI action must be linked to a function call so of I can 'catch' the call when a click event happens, I can associate the action with the call.

Comment: Macro recording and replay only records click location and replay by simulating a click on that location, which does nothing to link to the actual intended action

Comment: One more yhing: just looked up cbt and it seems like a thing to program within the software. I am looking for a way to catch calls from legacy software for which I don't have access to the code.